# How to get time at which notification is to be fired in Service before notify()

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to access the time in milliseconds at which the notification is scheduled while showing notification. How can I get it in Service? Alarm is scheduled in Activity. Based on that time, notification is to be altered. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While scheduling the alarm using pending intent you can add a key-value pair to the pending intent. Once you get the alarm in your broadcast receiver you would be able to retrieve the value and add logic to display the notification. Hope it helps! And yes don't forget to reschedule your alarms on events of phone being restarted etc..

Answer (score -1):

Step #1: Have your activity save the time it schedules the `Notification` for in a file, such as a `SharedPreferences`.

Step #2: Have your service read the time from that file.

You can optimize this a bit with an in-memory cache, but since I do not know your app, I have to assume that your process might be terminated between steps #1 and #2, which is why a file is important.